# Justification error in report format

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, report

I am writing my thesis using Kile. I encountered a mis-justification problem when creating table of contents, please see the uploaded picture. My institute insists to fix this. Can anybody help me on this?

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{OkanFBEStyle}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[nosort]{cite}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\pdfminorversion=5
 \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}.\hskip-0.5\subfiglabelskip}
\renewcommand{\@@thesubfigure}{\thefigure.\alph{subfigure}}
  \makeatother
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {calc}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{
>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
  \newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
  }
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Intramedullary Nailing}

\chapter{METHODS}
\section{Study 1: In modeling a distraction process, how should the tissue load be correctly represented in order to obtain a better understanding of the mechanical response of IM nails during limb lengthening?}
\subsection{Finite Element Model Considerations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: It is not obvious from this preamble what is the problem. What it the package `OkanFBEStyle`. Also change `\[` and `\]` with `[` and `]`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I updated my original question accordingly.

Comment: How shall I attach **OkanFBEStyle.sty** file?

Comment: You should always use the optional argument of `\section[short]{long}` to provide a _one line_ entry for the table of contents which looks _always_ much better than those long entries. And, of course, it is easier to read!

Comment: For your code to be a MWE you should exclude all packages that are irrelevant to replicate your problem.

Comment: this error is common to many document classes.  the space allowed for chapter and (sub)section numbers allows for only one digit at each level.  but doing the "right thing" requires a decision of where the numbers should be aligned -- at the right, or on the period following the chapter number, ...  the answer may not be the same for every document, even multiple documents based on the same class.  the decision requires the aid of a good designer, and the only solution i've seen so far is a complicated and ugly hack.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually correct. The first line is indented and the other lines are not. Admitedly this looks akward. Consider using different headings in the text and in the table of contents.

Example:

```
\section[Study 1: Chairs]{Study 1: The behaviour of chairs in the wilderness under the influence of time, love and water -- considering different frequencies of quantim flux compensation during recomfubeling phase.}
```

Edit:
As i understand the question it is about the alignment of the new lines in the section header with the indent of subsections.
The fastest way to get rid of that problem is to not have linebreaks. You can introduce alternative header by giving them as an optional argument. The table of contents will show the alternative header. You can now write a shorter header that is suitable for a table of contents and still preserve the long header in the actual text.

Rereading your questions, you may have asked wheather it is possible to have the indent of 3.1 be equal to the indent of 3.1.X. If that is the case you want to take a look at the [tocloft package](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/contents/tocloft.pdf). It allows you to configure the TOC.

Comment: I did not get your point. The problem is due to section part, but you are giving a subsection example? Could you please be more explanatory?